# echo in makefile.am if loop

Tags: makefile, automake

I am trying to have a prompt in `Makefile.am` if a condition is not true.
I am trying as:

```
if FOUND_MAKEDEPF90
<compilation condition if true>
else
@echo "Create the dependencies Manually\n"
@echo "e.g. ./src/main.o:./src/main.f90"
endif
```

The true branch is working properly, but, while running the else branch, I am getting error:

```
 *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Is it not valid to put an echo statement in the loop?
What is going wrong here? any idea please?

I am using:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a loop here. You have an make level if statement and yes, `echo` is a shell command and cannot be at the top-level of a makefile.

If you are just trying to display a message (at `make` run time) if that condition isn't met then you can use the make `$(info)` function (or `$(warning)` or `$(error)` which causes make to exit with an error).

Comment: `$(info Some text to display)`, etc. See [Functions That Control Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions).